# SQL Server 2008 backup tutorial

Tags: sql-server-2008, backup

I am using SQL Server 2008 Enterprise. I am looking for a database backup tutorial for a newbie. There are some good documents on MSDN which are about backup theories (e.g. different types of backup). What I am looking for and asking here is a step-by-step tutorial which is more practical (e.g. describe which option in GUI or command line is very important).

Any recommended tutorials? It is great if recovery is also described in the tutorial.

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out http://www.sqlservervideos.com/series/sqlserver-backups/

Comment: Thank you! Question answered!